# Loading SVGs within .scss with Webpack and svgr loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, sass

**Webpack config:**

1. For a `.svg` I use config:`{ test: /\.svg$/, use: ['svgr/webpack'] }`
2. For `.scss` I use `css-loader`, `postcss-loader` and `sass-loader`

**Folder structure:**

I have folder structure that looks like this:

```
- App
-- styles
--- globals.scss // Here I import my partials
--- partials
---- _my_partial.scss
-- icons
--- svgs
---- my_icon.svg
```

**svgr loader:**

I like `svgr loader` as it allows me to just import my icon and use it as React component:

```
import MyIcon from './icons/svgs/my_icon.svg';
...
<MyIcon />
```

**The actual problem:**

I was fine with this approach but I have to get one of the svgs as a `background-image`, so inside `_my_partial.scss` I wrote:

```
background-image: url(../icons/svgs/my_icon.svg);
```

I am up just one folder in this `url` as when being up two, it complained that it cannot resolve it - I guess this is because I import my partials in my `globals.scss`.

With this setup all I get in the browser is:

```
GET http://localhost:3005/[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: "I am up just one folder in this `url` as when being up two, it complained that it cannot resolve it". How did you write the import when being up two folders?

Comment: What I meant that when I wrote the path `../../icons/svgs/my_icon.svg` it complained that it cannot resolve it. It does not complain now, when I wrote `../icons/svgs/my_icon.svg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`svgr/webpack` turns your svg into react components, so when using svg into scss it's actually an object / react component. Change `svgr/webpack` to `file-loader` in order to use that. If you want to still use both, you could try something like:

```
{ test: /\.react.svg$/, use: ['svgr/webpack'] }
{ test: /\.svg$/, use: ['file-loader'] }
```

then rename all the svg's that you want as React components to **filename**.react.svg and the rest just leave with .svg.

I haven't tested this though :)

**UPDATE**: Looking at the documentation (section: **Handle SVG in CSS, Sass or Less**), it seems you can use svgr/webpack with file-loader:

https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr/tree/master/packages/webpack

```
{
  {
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    issuer: {
      test: /\.jsx?$/
    },
    use: ['babel-loader', '@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader'
  },
}
```

Either way, you probably need to make a few changes to fit in your needs but it supports it :)

Comment: That's a pretty good way to solve it, but when in need to use the same svg both in component and in the css, I have to have the same file in 2 versions.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can now import it both as a file and as a component from the same file :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't read to the end of the docs :( That `issuer` config made it to work!

Comment: It looks like the Webpack API has changed a little. I got what I needed by setting `issuer: { not: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/ },` but If you want a positive opt in to js/jsx closer to the answer above rather than a negative against stylesheets, simply `issuer: /\.jsx?$/,` should do it.

Comment: this didn't work for me but the answer on the main svgr website did the trick: https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/#use-svgr-and-asset-svg-in-the-same-project